# While loop wont run until tray icon is closed

Tags: python

```
import pystray
import PIL.Image


from datetime import datetime
from text_to_speech import speak
from time import time, sleep
import os
from gtts import gTTS
import vlc

image = PIL.Image.open('hourglass.jpg')
def on_clicked(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
icon = pystray.Icon('Hourglass', image, menu=pystray.Menu(
        pystray.MenuItem('Exit', on_clicked)))
icon.run()

stop = False ## To loop forever
while stop == False:
    print('test')
    now = datetime.now()
    second = now.second
    minute = now.minute
    if second == 0 :
        myText = 'It is now ' + (now.strftime("%I %p"))
        print(myText)
        output = gTTS(text=myText, lang='en', slow=False)
        output.save("Time.mp3")
        p = vlc.MediaPlayer("Time.mp3")
        p.play()
        sleep(10)
        os.remove("Time.mp3")
```

this is my code. For some reason which i cant figure out until i press on the icon and exit, the rest of the code wont run. I was trying to make an icon try for when i run this in the background.

Answer (score 2):

The `icon.run()` internally run a loop. So until this loop breaks (by closing the window) the code below will not be executed. If you want for the icon and the code below to run independently, you can use Threads.

```
import threading

def run_icon():
    icon = pystray.Icon('Hourglass', image, menu=pystray.Menu(
        pystray.MenuItem('Exit', on_clicked)))
    icon.run()

def run_second():
    stop = False ## To loop forever
    while stop == False:
        print('test')
        now = datetime.now()
        second = now.second
        minute = now.minute
        if second == 0 :
            myText = 'It is now ' + (now.strftime("%I %p"))
            print(myText)
            output = gTTS(text=myText, lang='en', slow=False)
            output.save("Time.mp3")
            p = vlc.MediaPlayer("Time.mp3")
            p.play()
            sleep(10)
            os.remove("Time.mp3")

Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_icon)
Thread2 = threading.Thread(target=run_second)

Thread1.join() # wait for thread to stop
Thread2.join() # wait for thread to stop
```

Comment: Ohhhh i did not know threading was a thing. I will have to learn this. Is there an easier way to achieve what i was trying to do or is threading the correct way?

Comment: I think that threading is the correct way. Maybe, there is a way to run ico.run() as a  non-blocking command, but I really doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `icon.run_detached()`. Then just run your main code underneath.